# Bootstrap 5 won't able to support mobile breakpoint on padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a sample here, but the breakpoint for mobile doesn't take effect with code `p-xs-5`. I have tried 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and auto, but none of them are working.

```
<div class="p-5">Text</div>
<div class="p-xs-1">Text</div>
<div class="p-xs-2">Text</div>
<div class="p-xs-3">Text</div>
<div class="p-xs-4">Text</div>
<div class="p-xs-5">Text</div>
<div class="p-xs-auto">Text</div>
```

Here is the link on codepen to play around

https://codepen.io/dotku/pen/QWrNJaE

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I realized that actually there isn't `xs` in breakpoint for spacing. The smallest starts from `sm`